# How to split large nested set into separate sets?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, set

Hi I have a set of data which I extracted from an api and I am trying to split the data in the set down into separate sets since currently they are all nested in the larger set.

My current set:

```
api = {
  "9/30/2018": {
    "Capital Expenditure": "-13313000", 
    "End Cash Position": "25913000", 
    "Financing Cash Flow": "-87876000", 
    "Free Cash Flow": "64121000", 
    "Income Tax Paid Supplemental Data": "10417000", 
    "Interest Paid Supplemental Data": "3022000", 
    "Investing Cash Flow": "16066000", 
    "Issuance of Capital Stock": "669000", 
    "Issuance of Debt": "6969000", 
    "Operating Cash Flow": "77434000", 
    "Repayment of Debt": "-6500000", 
    "Repurchase of Capital Stock": "-72738000"
  }, 
  "9/30/2019": {
    "Capital Expenditure": "-10495000", 
    "End Cash Position": "50224000", 
    "Financing Cash Flow": "-90976000", 
    "Free Cash Flow": "58896000", 
    "Income Tax Paid Supplemental Data": "15263000", 
    "Interest Paid Supplemental Data": "3423000", 
    "Investing Cash Flow": "45896000", 
    "Issuance of Capital Stock": "781000", 
    "Issuance of Debt": "6963000", 
    "Operating Cash Flow": "69391000", 
    "Repayment of Debt": "-8805000", 
    "Repurchase of Capital Stock": "-66897000"
  }, 
  "9/30/2020": {
    "Capital Expenditure": "-7309000", 
    "End Cash Position": "39789000", 
    "Financing Cash Flow": "-86820000", 
    "Free Cash Flow": "73365000", 
    "Income Tax Paid Supplemental Data": "9501000", 
    "Interest Paid Supplemental Data": "3002000", 
    "Investing Cash Flow": "-4289000", 
    "Issuance of Capital Stock": "880000", 
    "Issuance of Debt": "16091000", 
    "Operating Cash Flow": "80674000", 
    "Repayment of Debt": "-12629000", 
    "Repurchase of Capital Stock": "-72358000"
  }, 
  "ttm": {
    "Capital Expenditure": "-9646000", 
    "End Cash Position": "35276000", 
    "Financing Cash Flow": "-94328000", 
    "Free Cash Flow": "94768000", 
    "Income Tax Paid Supplemental Data": "19627000", 
    "Interest Paid Supplemental Data": "2597000", 
    "Investing Cash Flow": "-9849000", 
    "Issuance of Capital Stock": "1011000", 
    "Issuance of Debt": "22370000", 
    "Operating Cash Flow": "104414000", 
    "Repayment of Debt": "-7500000", 
    "Repurchase of Capital Stock": "-83410000"
  }
}
```

My desired outcome would be:
s_19_30_2018 = ["Capital Expenditure": "-13313000"...]

s_19_30_2019 = ["Capital Expenditure": "-10495000"...]

s_19_30_2020 = ["Capital Expenditure": "-7309000"...]

s_ttm = ["Capital Expenditure": "-9646000"...]

This is so that I can access the data with  more ease and add them to a sql database.

I have tried by doing s_19_30_2018 = api['19/30/2018'] but I keep getting 'type error string indices must be integers '.

Any help would be appreciated in python >.<

Comment: Doing `s_19_30_2018 = api["9/30/2018"]` seems to work, are you sure that `api`` is a dictionary?

Comment: There is no set here.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I tried it but I keep getting  s_18 = api["9/30/2018"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Thats because api is not a dictionary, is a string. Or the error refers to some other part of the code

Comment: There is no need for a variable like `s_19_30_2019`. If your data set is `api` then instead of `s_19_30_2019` just refer to `api["9/30/2019"]`. What you are asking for is to create dynamically-named variables. But in Python the way to do that is to use a dictionary, which you already have. If doing `api["9/30/2019"]` gives you an error message about string indices then the data is not as you have described it, because that would indicate that `api` is a string and your question shows it as a dictionary. If this data is JSON then look at the `json` module to turn it into a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this structure:

```
api = {
  "9/30/2018": {
    "Capital Expenditure": "-13313000", 
    "End Cash Position": "25913000", 

  }, 
  "9/30/2019": {
  ....
```

to get a list of key,values for the first entry can run:

```
for key,value in api["9/30/2018"]:
  l = [key, value]
  print(f" {key}, {value}")
  # prints "Capital Expenditure -133313000"
```

to go through all the items

```
#get the keys
ks = api.keys()
for k in ks:
  for key, value, in api[k]:
    print(f" {key}, {value}")
      # prints "Capital Expenditure -133313000"] ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary keys are string so use quotes when you access them like

```
s_19_30_2018 = api["9/30/2018"]
```

also I don't see any key such as "19_30_2018" in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
ks = api.keys()
for k in ks:
  for key, value, in api[k]:
    print(f" {key}, {value}")
```

By using code you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

by using the following code .....you can solve your problem

```
ks = api.keys()
    for k in ks:
      for key, value, in api[k]:
        print(f" {key}, {value}")
```

Comment: Can you explain how this code will fix his issue ? I suggest you to [edit] your answer and add more details :)